# Why does this javascript split function replace \1?

Tags: javascript, regex

I cannot understand the function used below that just splits a string on '.'.

Could you help me understand why it uses the extra replace statements?

```
function dotSplit (str) {
  return str.replace(/\1/g, '\u0002LITERAL\\1LITERAL\u0002')
    .replace(/\\\./g, '\u0001')
    .split(/\./).map(function (part) {
      return part.replace(/\1/g, '\\.')
      .replace(/\2LITERAL\\1LITERAL\2/g, '\u0001')
    })
}
```

Comment: You can test regex here: https://regex101.com

Comment: Thanks. I tested and it can split string via dot. but I cannot understand /\1/g in the regex, what it stands for?

Comment: the /g represents "global" (searches for all occurrences in a string rather than just first occurrence)

Comment: I know '\1' can refer to the first matched group, but here no match group in the regex, so what the '\1' means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, `\1` means to match the character whose octal representation in Latin-1 encoding is 1. That character is `SOH`, or the start of heading character. What it does above is replace all occurrences of that with `\u0002LITERAL\\1LITERAL\u0002`, where `\u2002` stands for the character `STX(Start of text).`

You can try it here:

https://regex101.com/r/n9LaJY/1

Comment: In JavaScript, [octal escapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Unicode_escape_sequences) use codes from the Latin-1 character set, not ASCII. JavaScript doesn't use ASCII at all. IMO, \u0001 would be preferred since JavaScript strings use UTF-16.